# Compile different code blocks for ios and android on react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, webpack, cross-platform

I have read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code) article in react native documentation. My question is how can I compile the js bundle differently for android and ios?

For example let's say I want to add a few lines of code for iOS inside a function. According to the mentioned article, I have to either use `Platform.OS` and check the platform on runtime or use .ios.js and .android.js files and let webpack use the correct static file.
The problem with the first approach is it may make the bundle big (if we have lots of these situations and the codes are big enough) and the problem with the second approach is that if the difference is not much for every change for the common code between the platform I have to change 2 files!

Isn't there any way to have a hybrid approach to consider platform specific code blocks while creating the bundle?

Comment: I don't get it why should it make your bundle big? The article just describes that you either can use an if condition or a specific file implementation!?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze Thanks; Even if the bundle size would be the same I want to know if this is possible or not :)

Comment: I think i don't understand what you're trying to achieve. I think if you have something like `BigButton.android.js` it won't be include in your iOS build.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with `BigButton.android.js`. The problem is if `BigButton.android.js` and `BigButton.ios.js` share code, you have to change two files for each modification. Is there any one liner or anything like compiler directives to compile codes for specific platform only?

Comment: this is your "compiler directive": `Platform.OS === 'ios'`

Comment: This would be evaluated on runtime rather than compile time! That's what I have already mentioned in the question!

Comment: [something like this?](https://medium.com/byteagenten/conditional-compilation-for-javascript-using-babel-5a6db5964422)